# Update two columns of two tables using inner join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in which there are two common columns (`isActive` & `group_id`)
I want to update the `isActive` column of two table joining the `group_id`.

This is the query I tried but it shows error.

```
UPDATE A set isActive = 0, B.isActive = 0
from OperatorGrouping A   
inner join OperatorGroupingSteps B 
on A.group_id = B.group_id   
where A.group_id = 9
```

Comment: Including the exact error message will help. You should also consider including the table definitions & a subset of sample data if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update statement only used to update values of one table at an instance. If you try to update two table column an error(Msg 41104) will occur. 
To Update columns in both tables as per requirement write separate code for the second table. e.g

```
UPDATE A 
     set A.isActive = 0
from OperatorGrouping A
inner join OperatorGroupingSteps B on A.group_id = B.group_id
where A.group_id = 9;

UPDATE B
    set B.isActive = 0 
 from OperatorGroupingSteps B
inner join OperatorGrouping A on A.group_id = B.group_id
where A.group_id = 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break your UPDATE statements into two parts

```
--Update A
    UPDATE A
      SET 
          A.isActive = 0
    FROM OperatorGrouping A
         INNER JOIN OperatorGroupingSteps B ON A.group_id = B.group_id
    WHERE A.group_id = 9;
--Update B
    UPDATE B
      SET 
          B.isActive = 0
    FROM OperatorGroupingSteps B
         INNER JOIN OperatorGrouping AB ON B.group_id = A.group_id
    WHERE A.group_id = 9;
```